# Функция не работает так как нужно

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт для очистки поля формы и для возвращения старого значения

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input')
    .each(function (i, el) {
    $(el).data('oldValue', $(el).val());
})
    .focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('oldValue')) $(this).val('');
})
    .blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length === 0) $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'));
});
});
```

Он работает так как нужно  http://jsfiddle.net/uUNs3/7/ 
то есть, если какое-то значение в поле уже введено, то при повторном фокусе на этом поле это значение никуда не пропадает и его можно допечатывать

Пытаюсь вынести этот код в отдельную функцию

```
$.fn.fill_contacts_input = function () {
$(this).each(function () {
    $(this).each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).data('oldValue', $(el).val());
    })
    .focus(function () {
        $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val());
        $(this).val('');
    })
        .blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
            $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'));
        }
    });
});
return $(this);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').fill_contacts_input();
});
```

Но при этом функция не работает так как нужно - если в поле введено какое-то новое значение, то при повторном клике оно пропадает.
http://jsfiddle.net/44LrW/11/

Как можно сделать, чтобы код, вынесенный в отдельную функцию, работал так же, как в первом примере ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну лишнего просто наколбасили, двойной each... Попробуйте так:

```
$.fn.fill_contacts_input = function () {
    $(this).each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).data('oldValue', $(el).val());
    });
    $(this).focus(function () {
        $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val());
        $(this).val('');
    })
      .blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
            $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'));
        }
    });
    return $(this);
};
```

Comment: Нет, с одним each то же самое получается http://jsfiddle.net/44LrW/12/  
Если какое-то новое значение введено, то при повторном клике оно исчезает.

Comment: @Heidel, так у вас разный код для focus в первом варианте и во втором, только что заметил.

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо больше, по невнимательности ошибка, вроде теперь все работает http://jsfiddle.net/44LrW/13/